# Sharepoint Designer 2013 - Workflow contents empty

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow

I am trying to access a workflow which was created by one of our clients.

When I click on 'Edit Workflow' and open the workflow I get the below (i.e. workflow empty):

[image]

Actual Workflow:

[image]
I am a Site Collection Administrator and Site Owner so permissions should not be a problem.

The workflow basically gets some data from the list and sets some tasks.

The client has informed me that the workflow has been saved and published multiple times.

I have also cleared the SPD2013 cache to no avail.

What can be causing this issue?

Comment: Did you try copy/paste WF in SPD? Like to same site but just to make it duplicate and check if it is again empty. Also, Is there anybody else with your level of permissions to check if he/she can open WF?

Answer (score 1):

- Try to install this update http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2837633
- If not worked try to reinstall SharePoint designer and install it again.
  Maybe the issue is related  to order of installation of designer and Visio. so try to uninstall both and  Install visio first, then SharePoint designer.